# Missing article in the admin panel

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator

I posted a recent article on the  website, one of the users logged in the admin panel logged in and tried to edit the article accidentally the article disappeared and I can't get it. I have searched under trashed, archived but I still can  not find it. How do I find the article?

Comment: Have you used something like phpMyAdmin to check the '#__content' table to see if there is a record there that matches the article you have lost. It might just be a case of changing the 'state' field to 1 for the article to re-appear. Or at least you might find if there is any article left to find. 
If it is there in the database table and the State is correct then you might be looking at an issue of permission or incorrect category.

Comment: @Irata Yes I use the phpMyAdmin and the article exist in the database with the state field is 1 and the Category is correct. Kindly elaborate on permission?

Comment: In your OP you mention Admin but not whether the Admin or you is a Super User. Unless you are logged in as a Super User then the article may not be displayed to you due to it not being visible to the view level(s) that are visible to your login.

Comment: I am logged in as an Admin nit the Super Admin

Comment: When you find the article in the DB using phpMyAdmin look in the column called 'access' in the '#__contents' and it will have a number. You take that number and look in table '#__viewlevels' for that number in the ID column and that will tell you what View Level of Access that you need to be able to see the article. Or change the value in 'access' in the '#__content' table to a '2' and it should be available to 'Registered' so you should be able to see it. However if you are not the 'Super User', you should be contacting the person that is for help and not bypass security as explained.

Comment: Thanks for this I changed the access levels and I was able to get view and edit the article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you find the article in the DB using phpMyAdmin look in the column called 'access' in the '#__contents' and it will have a number. You take that number and look in table '#__viewlevels' for that number in the ID column and that will tell you what View Level of Access that you need to be able to see the article. Or change the value in 'access' in the '#__content' table to a '2' and it should be available to 'Registered' so you should be able to see it. However if you are not the 'Super User', you should be contacting the person that is for help and not bypass security as explained.